# How to fix Contact Form not going to next validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

The first two title and name validation works but it also everytime refreshes page which is also an issue.

But after name gets validated email doesnt get validated and all the other ones aswell like the dropbox, checkbox, and msg if theyre empty.

**CODE**

```js
function checkData() {


  if (document.signup.TITLE.value == "") {
    alert("Please select your Title.")
    document.signup.TITLE.focus()
    return false;

  }

  if (document.signup.NAME.value == "" || document.signup.NAME.value.length < 2 || isNaN.document.signup.NAME.value) {
    alert("Please fill in your Name.")
    document.signup.NAME.focus()
    return false;

  }




  if (document.signup.EMAIL.value == "") {
    alert("Please fill in your E-Mail address.")
    document.signup.EMAIL.focus()
    return false;

  }

  if (document.signup.ENQ.value == "") {
    alert("Please select your Enquiry.")
    document.signup.ENQ.focus()
    return false;

  }

  if (document.signup.INS.value == "") {
    alert("Please select your Insurance.")
    document.signup.INS.focus()
    return false;

  }
  if (document.signup.MSG.value == "") {
    alert("Please type in your Message.")
    document.signup.MSG.focus()
    return false;

  } else {

    return true;
  }



}
```

```html
<form name="signup" onsubmit="return checkData()">

  <td>
    Title:*
  </td>

  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="TITLE" value="TITLE">Mr
    <input type="radio" name="TITLE" value="TITLE">Mrs
    <input type="radio" name="TITLE" value="TITLE">Miss
    <input type="radio" name="TITLE" value="TITLE">Ms
  </td>

  <tr>

    <td>Your Name: </td>

    <td>
      <input name="NAME" type="text" id="NAME" />

    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>E-Mail:</td>
    <td>
      <input name="EMAIL" type="text" id="EMAIL" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-------->
  <tr>
    <td>
      Enquiry:*
    </td>
    <td>

      <select>
        <option name="ENQ" value="S">Select Option</option>
        <option name="ENQ" value="sg">Suggestion</option>
        <option name="ENQ" value="sg">Complaint</option>
        <option name="ENQ" value="sg">Cancellation</option>
      </select>


      </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <!-------->
  <tr>
    <td>
      Select Insurance
    </td>

    <td>
      <div id="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="INS" id="INS" value="INS" />Insuarance
        <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" name="INS" id="INS"/>Fees</label>
        <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" name="INS" id="INS"/>Black Box</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Message:
    </td>

    <td>
      <textarea name="MSG" rows="5" cols="80" id "MSG"></textarea>

    </td>
    <tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>

        <td>
          <input type="submit" value="Email This Form">
        </td>

      </tr>



</form>
```

Here is the code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qwWPwq

Comment: please add the code HERE.. thanks

Comment: You given return true statement in message else part instead of giving function end

Answer (score 0):

Your code is breaking before you even get to the email validator.  There are some issues with your name check.

```
if (document.signup.NAME.value == "" || document.signup.NAME.value.length < 2 || isNaN.document.signup.NAME.value )
```

`isNaN` is a function, but you are using in it in a way that implies it has some `document` property, which it doesn't, so that code breaks when it runs before your email check even gets to occur. Your third condition should be written as:

```
isNaN(document.signup.NAME.value)
```

**BUT** while that is now correct syntax, this is not the validation check you should use. Per the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) `isNan()` always returns `true` for strings so this check will ALWAYS think your name is invalid. Remove it so you simply have:

```
if (document.signup.NAME.value.trim() == "" || document.signup.NAME.value.length < 2)
```

**EDIT**
There seem to be some issues with your ENQ and Insurance checks as well. I modified them below. I also added `trim()` to all your empty string checks to prevent whitespace only input from validating. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z3aso7u0/

```js
document.querySelector('[name="signup"]').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkData();
})

function checkData() {
  if (document.signup.TITLE.value == "") {
    alert("Please select your Title.")
    document.signup.TITLE.focus()
    return false;

  }

  if (document.signup.NAME.value.trim() == "" || document.signup.NAME.value.length < 2) {
    alert("Please fill in your Name.")
    document.signup.NAME.focus()
    return false;
  }

  if (document.signup.EMAIL.value.trim() == "") {
    alert("Please fill in your E-Mail address.")
    document.signup.EMAIL.focus()
    return false;

  }

  if (document.signup.ENQ.value == "S") {
    alert("Please select your Enquiry.")
    document.signup.ENQ.focus()
    return false;

  } 

  if (!document.signup.INS.checked && !document.signup.FEES.checked && !document.signup.BB.checked) {
    alert("Please select your Insurance.")
    document.signup.INS.focus()
    return false;

  }
  if (document.signup.MSG.value.trim() == "") {
    alert("Please type in your Message.")
    document.signup.MSG.focus()
    return false;

  }

  return true;
  
}
```

```html
<form name="signup">
  <td>
    Title:*
  </td>

  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="TITLE" value="TITLE">Mr
    <input type="radio" name="TITLE" value="TITLE">Mrs
    <input type="radio" name="TITLE" value="TITLE">Miss
    <input type="radio" name="TITLE" value="TITLE">Ms
  </td>

  <tr>

    <td>Your Name: </td>

    <td>
      <input name="NAME" type="text" id="NAME" />

    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>E-Mail:</td>
    <td>
      <input name="EMAIL" type="text" id="EMAIL" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-------->
  <tr>
    <td>
      Enquiry:*
    </td>
    <td>

      <select name="ENQ" id="ENQ">
        <option name="ENQ" value="S">Select Option</option>
        <option name="ENQ" value="sg">Suggestion</option>
        <option name="ENQ" value="sg">Complaint</option>
        <option name="ENQ" value="sg">Cancellation</option>
      </select>

  <!-------->
  <tr>
    <td>
      Select Insurance
    </td>

    <td>
      <div id="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="INS" id="INS" value="INS" />Insuarance
        <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" name="FEES" id="FEES"/>Fees</label>
        <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" name="BB" id="BB"/>Black Box</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Message:
    </td>

    <td>
      <textarea name="MSG" rows="5" cols="80" id "MSG"></textarea>

    </td>
    <tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>

        <td>
          <input type="submit" value="Email This Form">
        </td>

      </tr>

</form>
```

Comment: Very Nice, Solution it fixed it, but when I copy the code to pc I can see that  this part ``` document.querySelector('[name="signup"]').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkData();
}) ``` Is preventing the notification to pop up. When I delete that part the alerts come up but the page only refreshes at the begining if title is not selected. Is there some kind of special linking to the html required because I only have ``` onsubmit="return checkData()" ? When I delete that link and keep the first 4 lines in the java script then validation is not working.